# Get total count in addition of count if user voted

Tags: mysql, sql

Got three tables I'm joining. `submissions`, `submissions_votes`, and `users`.

I want to find out how many total helpfulVotes there are (which is a sum of the count of all `submissions_votes`) and I've got that.

I also want to return a count (boolean, rather) of 0 or 1 if the `user_id` of `sv.user_id` relates to the submission being viewed. The `user_id` is passed in to the `WHERE` clause.

```
    SELECT s.*,
      u.username,
      u.photo as userPhoto,
      COALESCE(SUM(sv.up), 0) helpfulVotes
    FROM
      submissions s
    LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv on s.id = sv.submission_id WHERE u.id = ?
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON s.user_id = u.id
```

I know I need an additional join (on `sv.user_id = u.id`) but what would I select? Then would I group by `sv.id`?

Edit:

`users` table:

```
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type                   | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| email          | varchar(128)           | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| username       | varchar(23)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| type           | enum('normal','admin') | NO   |     | normal            |                             |
| about          | varchar(255)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| photo          | varchar(32)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

`submissions_votes` table:

```
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| submission_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| when          | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| up            | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| down          | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`submissions` table:

```
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(255)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | mediumtext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created     | datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type        | enum('tip','request')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| thumbnail   | varchar(64)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| removed     | tinyint(1) unsigned                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| keywords    | varchar(255)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip          | int(10) unsigned                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: provide your table structure, to assist you further. We are making some assumptions and if that does not match your structure code will not be useful.

Comment: In order to count each submission's votes, you must necessarily group the votes table by submission; but in so doing, it becomes meaningless to refer to (the `user_id` of) *the* vote associated with that submission: there could be a great many of them.  Thus you need to define your problem better, which is often most easily done with an illustrative example of table contents and desired results.  One might hazard a guess that the boolean is supposed to indicate whether at least one of the votes were cast by the submission's owner, but that isn't at all clear from your question.

Comment: @bob_cobb: The statement as is looks wrong to me. You sum up all upvotes of one user's submissions, then display the user and a random submission record with it. This is certainly not what you want, right?

Comment: @eggyal I should have mentioned that it should match the current userId being passed in. Edited post.

Comment: @bob_cobb: You placed the WHERE clause incorrectly. So you want to show how many upvotes a user's submissions got in total plus wether he/she him/herself voted for at least one of his/her own submissions?

Comment: @bob_cobb You asked two questions. 1. You said "find out how many total helpfulVotes". Is this a `SUM` per user & submission, or per user, or just per submission? 2. What is "submission being viewed"? There is no `WHERE` clause in your statement to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `sv.user_id` = input `user_id` using `CASE` and `SUM` it up (grouped by each submission). If the SUM is 1, then the input user_id has a submission, otherwise not. *So, your input user_id would go into the CASE function.*

Also, the `COALESCE(SUM(sv.up), 0)` requires a grouping by whichever columns of `submissions` and `users` tables are selected.

The following is the query based on the tables in the **[SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d9c3/15)**.

```
SELECT 
  s.id as submission_id,
  s.title as submission_title,
  MAX(u.email) as submission_user_email,
  COALESCE(SUM(sv.up), 0) helpfulVotes,
  SUM(CASE sv.user_id
      WHEN ? THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END) User_Submission
FROM
  submissions s
LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv on s.id = sv.submission_id
INNER JOIN USERS u
ON s.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY s.id, s.title;
```

(If more columns from the `submissions` table need to be selected, then they need to be either grouped or aggregated)

Comment: Yes, this should work... although wide `GROUP BY`s or aggregates often crimp performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need an additional join.  Just a boolean expression in the `select`:

```
SELECT s.*,
       u.username,
       u.photo as userPhoto,
       COALESCE(SUM(sv.up), 0) helpfulVotes,
       SUM(sv.user_id = u.id) as SubmissionUserMatches
FROM submissions s LEFT JOIN
     submissions_votes sv
     on s.id = sv.submission_id INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON s.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY s.id, u.username, u.photo;
```

Comment: `sv.user_id` is a hidden/non-aggregated column, so the results here will be indeterminate.  For that matter, in this solution `s.*` are too (although I suspect the OP intends to group by `s.id`).

Comment: @eggyal . . . I added the `group by` which probably fixes the OP's original problem.  Thank you for pointing that out.  And an aggregation to count the number of votes made by the submitter for the submission.

Comment: Yet grouping by those columns doesn't change the point made in my first comment: `sv.user_id` is hidden and thus your `SubmissionUserMatches` values will be indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

I use mssql so don't know for sure if my answer works for mysql. In mssql the query in the question would not work without a group by. if you did leave the group by out,You should include srsv.submission_id in the group by.
Assuming you have a constraint that makes sure there is only on submission_vote per submission and user the following should work:

```
SELECT s.*,
  u.username,
  u.photo as userPhoto,
  COALESCE(SUM(sv.up), 0) helpfulVotes
  case when srsv.submission_id is null then 1 else 0 end SelfRelatedVote
FROM
  submissions s
LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv on s.id = sv.submission_id
Left JOIN submissions_votes srsv on s.id = srsv.submission_id and s.user_id = srsv.user_id
INNER JOIN users u
ON s.user_id = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
SELECT s.*,
  u.username,
  COALESCE(SUM(sv.up), 0) helpfulVotes,
  IF (srsv.submission_id is null, 1, 0)
FROM
  submissions s
LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv on s.id = sv.submission_id
LEFT JOIN submissions_votes srsv on s.id = srsv.submission_id and s.user_id = {USER_ID}
INNER JOIN users u ON s.user_id = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the total for all submissions , and the total for the submissions only for the user (Or other user specific aggregations) , you can join to the submission_votes table twice, with a different alias for the second connection to the table. This will allow any aggregation on user specific Submission_Vote details.

This is pseudo code - the GROUP BY s.* will have to be replaced by the fields you are selecting and grouping by:

```
SELECT 
     s.*
    ,u.username
    ,u.photo                        AS  userPhoto
    ,COALESCE(SUM(sv.up), 0)        AS  helpfulVotes
    ,COALESCE(SUM(sv_user.up), 0)   AS  helpfulVotes_user
FROM
    submissions s

    LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv 
    on s.id = sv.submission_id 

    LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv_user
    on s.id = sv_user.submission_id 

    INNER JOIN users u
    ON s.user_id = u.id

WHERE
    sv_user.user_id = @User_id
GROUP BY
     s.*
    ,u.username
    ,u.photo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what the boolean is supposed to indicate but I assume it's whether there is at least 1 vote by the supplied user_id in submission_votes because if all votes in submission_votes are supposed to be related to user_id, then the boolean would be redundant as one could just look at the count.

I think subqueries are the way to go. Try something like this:

```
SELECT s.*,
      u.username,
      u.photo as userPhoto,
      COALESCE(
      (
        SELECT SUM(sv.up) FROM
        submission_votes sv
        WHERE sv.submission_id = s.id
      ), 0) helpfulVotes,
      (CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM submission_votes 
            WHERE sv.submission_id = s.id 
            AND sv.user_id = ?)
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0
       END) userSubmissionVoteExists
    FROM
    submissions s
    INNER JOIN users u ON s.user_id = u.id
```